# ROS Serial Exception Missing File

Tags: serial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have a node running in ROS Indigo which makes use of the serial library. I've used it on other machines in the past without any issues. My current system is an ODroid XU4.

When I go to run the node however I get the following error:

```
odroid@odroid:~/Control_Code$ rosrun imu imu_node 
[ INFO] [1469661666.648402551]: running...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'serial::IOException'
  what():  IO Exception (2): No such file or directory, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-serial-1.2.1/src/impl/unix.cc, line 151.
Aborted
```

Looking in synaptic I have

```
ros-indigo-serial
ros-indigo-serial-utils
```

With the following includes:
#include "ros/ros.h"

```
#include "serial/serial.h"

#include "ros/time.h"

#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <string>

#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

#include <ios>

#include <stdint.h>
```

I have no idea where this error is coming from. Has anyone seen this before? What other troubleshooting steps can I take?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240535/ros-serial-exception-missing-file/) by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 124 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The serial port you are trying to open does not exist. This is a runtime error, so it doesn't have anything to do with the files you are including at compile time (they're all there otherwise it wouldn't compile).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2016-07-27**:
That was it, I dug around more and found that the path hadn't been updated.

Thanks!

**Comment by [ss4771](https://answers.ros.org/users/28180/ss4771/) on 2016-10-07**:
New to ROS here- what did you do to update your path?

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-25**:
hello, I would like to know as well. Please advice.

**Comment by [halfeld](https://answers.ros.org/users/114664/halfeld/) on 2022-08-19**:
Look for your device with `ls /dev`. If none of the entries match the one you are calling when running your nodes, this error message will appear.